# keyboard is disappearing automatically flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using "intl_phone_number_input" package ,,,

https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_number_input

but when I try to enter the number, the keyboard disappears automatically,

can anyone help me ??

Comment: It's working for me. Which emulator/mobile are you using?

Comment: I am using it on my real phone and on the emulator, it's always close the keyboard automatically